# Landscape drawable folder for kindle fire hd 8.9

Tags: android, kindle-fire, android-drawable

I am working on a kindle fire app which is supposed to run on all fire devices including Kindle Fire 1st Gen, HD-7 & HD-8.9.

For splash screen, I am using following drawble folders:

- drawable-mdpi - 1st gen kindle fire, portrait
- drawable-land-mdpi - 1st gen kindle fire, landscape
- drawable-hdpi - fire hd 7, portrait
- drawable-land-hdpi - fire hd 7, landscape
- drawable-sw800dp-hdpi - fire hd 8.9, portrait
- drawable-sw800dp-land-hdpi - fire hd 8.9, landscape

Now, all the images are displayed correctly EXCEPT for the one in `drawable-sw800dp-land-hdpi`. It's picking up the image from `drawable-land-hdpi` instead.

Please someone tell me what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Thanks RKN for nice formatting.

Answer (score 1):

drawable-normal-hdpi (Normal Devices)

drawable-large-mdpi (Kindle Fire 1st and 2nd generation 600*1024)

drawable-large-hdpi (Kindle Fire HD7 800*1280)

drawable-xlarge-hdpi (Kindle Fire HD9 1200*1920)

To configure Kindle Fire Emulators follow the below link

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/emulator-guide.html